# BootCamp 6 on MacBook Pro Early 11 - Unable to install Win10

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, install, plist

I just fresh install macOS Sierra on my MacBook Pro early 2011. Now I would love to install Win10 using BootCamp. When I launch the BootCamp utility and insert the Win10 DVD, an error message appear saying that Win10 is not supported for my MacBook. OK.

I search the Internet and found a way by modifying Info.plist and removing my Mac version in the UnsupportedWin10Model tag. I try to do that but the file seems to be locked (using sudo su and whoami returns root).

Is there any way to install Win10 on this "old" MacBook without having to install Win8 then update it to Win10 ?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 is not supported under Boot Camp for your particular Mac.  See the Apple Support Document:  [Use Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990).

If you are able to install Windows 7/8/8.1 and then *upgrade* to Windows 10 then this is the workaround you should do.